# Which nginx-config file is enabled, /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf or /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, centos6

There are two config files around, `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
and `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but which one is enabled?
I am running CentOS6.4 and nginx/1.0.15.

Answer (score 109):

Technically, `nginx.conf` is all that matters, if you define every thing inside there it would still work, but to keep things organized, they use `include`, somewhere at the end of `nginx.conf` you'll see `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*` and in some distros you'll also find `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` this is a convention to keep things organized, you create your server blocks in that `conf.d` or `sites-enabled` folder and it would be included here as if it's written in the `nginx.conf` file.

Of course you can add your own include lines there normally and create your own new conf folder that would be auto included.

**TIP**: These files are included in alphabetical order, you need to keep that in mind if you don't specify any server as `default_server`, because first one would be the default.

Answer (score 29):

the general configuration of nginx is in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` is used to configure the default virtual host. For this you can also use `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`.

You can find more details at a blog entry from digital ocean [How To Configure The Nginx Web Server On a Virtual Private Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-the-nginx-web-server-on-a-virtual-private-server)

Comment: I am just wondering whenever there is a conflict between `nginx.conf` and `conf.d/default.conf`, which one will take effect? I mean which one has a higher priority?

Answer (score 20):

for save time.

- if you just have 1 site to host, nginx.conf is ok. but,
- if you have 2~n sites, for more clear config, you should use **conf.d fold**.

[image: detail.]