# Return a string using the Nginx container

Tags: nginx

I am using the Nginx container to host a SPA application in Kubernetes.

Aside from the static files hosted for the SPA app, I also need to host the routes for health checks.  So, the route `/health/startup` needs to return the text `healthy` when a GET request is sent to it.

I suppose I could just make a folder called "health" and then put a file in it called startup with the text `healthy` in it.  But that seems a bit odd to me.  And I worry that if the file structure may get changed and that then my health checks will start failing.

**Is there a way, using the [Nginx container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) to return a given value (ie "healthy")when a request comes to a specific route?**  (And not mess up the rest of my static file serving that is going on.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can, in the configuration you are importing for the server, you can just do this:

```
location /health/startup {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 'healthy';
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect!  However, I don't know where the configuration file you refer to is located.  (The container image just works for static files dropped into `/usr/share/nginx/html`.)  Do you know where the configuration file is usually found?

Comment: it should be on `/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf`

Comment: also from the link you posted, under `Complex configuration` I see that the location might be `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (might also happen that you need a surrounding `server { ... }` to the snipped i've posted... depends on the version you are using)

Comment: Looks like `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the "real" one.  But, by default, it has this line at the bottom: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`  That makes `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` also get loaded.  It also means that any `.conf` file in that folder will get loaded. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164038/16241)  I will add a file to that location for my health checks.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Vaccano never dug that deep about Nginx config, that's new also for me, hope it works ahah good luck with K8s

Comment: Per site configurations can be in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` ...

Comment: `add_header Content-Type text/plain;` is not necessary