# what is the difference between nginx.conf and default file

Tags: nginx, configuration, default

I am new to Nginx I was looking at different lectures and some of them use the ngix.conf file to configure Nginx and others use /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file to configure it I would like to know the difference between ngix.conf file and /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @taylor.2317 is it more clear now?

Comment: I think your question is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143565/which-nginx-config-file-is-enabled-etc-nginx-conf-d-default-conf-or-etc-nginx.